# loading jqxgrid with local json data failed

Tags: html, ajax, jqxgrid

Hi am working on jqxgrid. Am trying to load this jqxgrid using a local json grid.

Below is the code what i tried so far. But am getting a blank grid.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/gettheme.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var jsonData = [{"creation_dt":"2011-04-08 00:00:00.0","request_deliv_dt":"2011-07-01 00:00:00.0”},
                {"creation_dt":"2011-04-08 00:00:00.0","request_deliv_dt":"2011-07-02 00:00:00.0"},
                {"creation_dt":"2011-04-08 00:00:00.0","request_deliv_dt":"2011-07-01 00:00:00.0"},
                {"creation_dt":"2011-04-08 00:00:00.0","request_deliv_dt":"2011-07-02 00:00:00.0"},
                {"creation_dt":"2011-04-08 00:00:00.0","request_deliv_dt":"2011-07-01 00:00:00.0"},
                {"creation_dt":"2011-04-08 00:00:00.0","request_deliv_dt":"2011-07-02 00:00:00.0"];
var jsonColumns = [{ text: 'creation_dt', datafield: 'creation_dt', width: 250 },{text:'request_deliv_dt', datafield: 'request_deliv_dt', width: 250 }];

var jsonFields = [{ name: 'creation_dt' },{ name: 'request_deliv_dt' }];

var source ={
                  datatype: "json",
                  datafields: jsonFields,
                  localdata: jsonData
            };
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
                        {
                            width: 670,
                            source: dataAdapter,
    columns: jsonColumns
                        });
                  });

});
    </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
    <div id='jqxWidget' style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana; float: left;">
        <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any problem in the above code..??

Can anyone help me to solve the issue.?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 errors in your code:

- the last '});' should not be there.
- missing '}' in your JSON